# SVG animation freezes with multiple elements

Tags: jquery, canvas, jquery-animate, line, raphael

I'm trying to use Raphael.js to animate an SVG path on a loop, but when I add more than 2 paths, the additional paths animating more than one time. It animates fine when I only have two paths, but as soon as I add another, it stops working correctly.

```js
var animateLine = function(canvas, colorNumber, pathString) {
 var line = canvas.path(pathString).attr({
  stroke: colorNumber
 });

 var length = line.getTotalLength();

 $('path[fill*="none"]').animate({
  'to': 1
 }, {
  duration: 5000,
  step: function(pos, fx) {
   var offset = length * fx.pos;
   var subpath = line.getSubpath(0, offset);
   canvas.clear();
   canvas.path(subpath).attr({
    stroke: colorNumber,
    "stroke-dasharray":"--",
    "stroke-width": '1.5'
   });
  }
 });
};

// Create path to be animated
var canvas0 = new Raphael('draw0', 234, 540.1);
var canvas1 = new Raphael('draw0', 234, 540.1);
var canvas2 = new Raphael('draw0', 234, 540.1);
var canvas3 = new Raphael('draw0', 234, 540.1);
var canvas4 = new Raphael('draw0', 234, 540.1);
var pathString = "M78.2,0.1c0,0,9.4,79.1,2.3,117  c-4.5,24.1-31.8,106.2-56.3,108.7c-12.7,1.3-24.2-11.9-16.5-15.5C15,207,40.2,231.1,19,261.7c-9.8,14.1-24.7,31.9-12.5,44.9  c11.3,12,53-36.8,59.2-23.8c8.6,18-40.8,23-28,49.2c14.7,30.4,21.6,39.9,48,58.5c31.3,22,147,66.2,147.2,149.5";

animateLine(canvas0, "#333", pathString);
animateLine(canvas1, "#333", pathString);
animateLine(canvas2, "#333", pathString);
animateLine(canvas3, "#333", pathString);
animateLine(canvas4, "#333", pathString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.8/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="draw0"></div>
<div id="draw1"></div>
<div id="draw2"></div>
<div id="draw3"></div>
<div id="draw4"></div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code in-line rather than in a jsfiddle link

Comment: In your [revision #3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57278738/3), you say that "the additional paths animating more than one time". Is the issue that all of the paths *are* animating more than one time as you've written, or rather that they stop animating and *do not loop*? Revision #2 captured the latter meaning, if that's what you are trying to describe.

Comment: Please turn on the full screen, then you can see better. each line has the same animation, and it has to animate only once and stay, and yet, several of them repeat the animation. Note that with the first loop each line animates the same. When it's done animating, the other three are still animating. later, the other two are animating and at the end one is animating. Summarizing:
1 loop - they all animate (correctly)
2 loops - 3 are animating (incorrectly)
3 loops - 2 animate (incorrectly)
4th loop - the last one animates (incorrectly)